# Multiway graph derived from a simple rule: why this first step?

Tags: logic, graph-theory

In https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/03/the-physicalization-of-metamathematics-and-its-implications-for-the-foundations-of-mathematics/#mathematics-and-physics-have-the-same-foundations

some examples are given of multiway graphs when applying a given rule. One of these examples is

[image]

I don't understand the first step of the derivation. From $a \circ x_$ applying the rule $x_ \longleftrightarrow y_$ left to right I see very well we get $ a \circ y_ $, but how do we get $ y_ \circ x_ $ applying it right to left.